# Why is input.next() sometimes being skipped?

Tags: java, loops, iterator

In my code (below), the `input.next();` is just skipped. Can someone please point out why?

```
for (int i=0; i<empNum; i++)//for each employee they want to work with
    {
        System.out.print("\r\n\r\nPROFILE FOR EMPLOYEE #" + (i+1) + ":\r\n"
                        +"type Hourly(1), Salaried(2), Salaried plus Commission(3)\r\n"
                        +"Enter 1, 2, or 3 ==> ");//display type gathering
        int typeChooser = input.nextInt();//gather type

        System.out.print("Name ==> ");//ask for name
        String name = input.next();//get name

        System.out.print("Social Security Number ==> ");//ask for ssn
        String ssn = input.next();//THIS PART IS SKIPPED

        System.out.print("Birthday Month (1-12) ==> ");//ask for bdayMonth
        int bdayMonth = input.nextInt();//get bdayMonth

        System.out.print("Birthday bonus week (1-4) ==> ");//ask for bdayWeek
        int bdayWeek = input.nextInt();//get bdayWeek            
}
```

EDIT: I just noticed that the only time it's skipped is when the name has a space in it (i.e. Bob Smith instead of just Bob)

Comment: Do get an exception at some point?

Comment: I ran the code on my computer and it worked just fine... What do you mean by "skipped"?

Comment: Many, many lines later, I get "Exception in thread 'main' java.util.InputMismatchException". I figured it was unrelated, but if you assumed it would be coming soon, maybe it isn't?

Comment: @Michael try running it with a space in the first name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Social Security Number contains whitespace? If it does, You can try **nextLine();** method. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end.

```
System.out.print("Social Security Number ==> ");//ask for ssn
String ssn = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: I was unaware that nextLine(); took the rest of the line - I thought that, as the name sort of implies, it takes the entire next line. This is the answer, and I'll mark it as such when possible. Thanks!

Comment: This answer will not work due to the previous call to `input.next()`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use a `Scanner` for this. Scanner by default uses whitespaces as a delimiter, so the `next()` method will only read until the next space, not the endline character. So if there are spaces in the input, you should use `nextLine()` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

Taking from Umut's answer, your code would look something like

```
 input.nextLine();
 System.out.print("Social Security Number ==> ");//ask for ssn
 String ssn = input.nextLine();
```

You need that first call to `nextLine()` because `input.next()` will not advance past the newline token

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())

> public String next()
>
> > Finds and returns the next complete token from
> >     this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that
> >     matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for
> >     input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned
> >     true.

So, when you have a space in your name input, next() returns only the first token, since its default delimiter is a space character and so remaining token(s) is/are still in the buffer which are then read first on the following call to next(). Use nextLine() here to eat up the whole line (default delimiter is '\n' for it), or you can prefer using BufferedReader instead.